# mysql self join performance

Tags: mysql, self-join

Image there is a table

```
CREATE TABLE `message`(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `content` text NOT NULL,
    `create_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `thumbs_up` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', /*Vote Count*/
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `thumbs_up_key` (`thumbs_up`,`id`)
)
```

from some artitle,is says,when doing paging query(or maybe irrelevant),
query using sql

```
select m2.* from message m1,message m2
where m1.id=m2.id and m1.thumbs_up <=98
and (m1.id<13 or m1.thumbs_up<98)
order by m1.thumbs_up desc,m1.id desc
```

is better than sql

```
select *
from message
where thumbs_up <=98 and (id<13 or thumbs_up<98)
order by thumbs_up desc,id desc
limit 100
```

why?

I read it on this article https://www.slideshare.net/suratbhati/efficient-pagination-using-mysql-6187107  , page 19

Thanks

Comment: maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com better place for this question.